# Adding file(s) to Dropzone freezes Firefox (v61)

Tags: javascript, firefox, queue, 64-bit, dropzone

Adding file(s) to Dropzone freezes Firefox (v61) for minutes while Chrome and Edge do not:

Within my Ember project/app there is a Dropzone file upload zone. When I add files to the queue FF will "freeze" for, say, a minute a file, until FF again is available for further interaction, like pressing the upload button.

This behaviour is independent of whether drag-and-drop or click-and-select is chosen.

This freezing does not happen if the chosen files are recently uploaded or handled within some minutes before, but if a single file of those selected are (apparently) "unknown" by FF, an at least minute-long delay will occur. Does this suggest a connection with caching...??? Confusing.

I do not know another way to break this "freeze" other than killing FF, which during this time is running constantly around 25% CPU (that is one of four CPUs at 100%). After kill, I cannot find any track of the cause or location of this heavy CPU activity.

FF fails on both Kubuntu and W10. This behaviour does not happen with Chrome or Edge.

The enclosed code describes is extracts only to show the basic idea. I am not considering any autoProcessQueue alternative, but wants an overview and edit opportunity before upload:

```js
...
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['dropzone'],
  ...
  parallelUploads: 8,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  thumbnailWidth: 100,
  thumbnailHeight: 100,
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  ... // all others null or empty
  ...
  init: function () {
    onDragEnterLeaveHandler(this);
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      document.getElementById("uploadPics").style.display = "inline"; // button processFileQueue 
      document.getElementById("removeAll").style.display = "inline";  // " removeAllFiles
      var namepic = file.name.replace(/.[^.]*$/, ""); // remove ext
      file.status = Dropzone.ADDED;
    });
    this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
      document.getElementById("uploadPics").style.display = "none";
    });
  },
  ...
  actions: {
    processFileQueue() {
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise ( () => {
        qlen = this.myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length;
        if (qlen > 0) {
          this.myDropzone.processQueue ();
        }
      }).then (null);
    },
    removeAllFiles() {
      this.myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
      document.getElementById("removeAll").style.display = "none";
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

Has anyone a clue of what is happening or how to start investgating what's happening?

Comment: why have you created a runnable snippet that can not possibly run :p

Comment: anything useful in the developer tools console? by the way, you're not using Promises correctly - therefore `processFileQueue` returns a Promise that is permanently **Pending**

Comment: Nothing useful in the console since all freezes. This is before processFileQueue is triggered. The file adding locks up everything, also that button. (yes: how should the promise be improved? it works if run)

Comment: what about after the freeze?

Comment: After the freeze all is normal, like another browser

Comment: have you tried FF 60, or even FF 62, to see if it's version specific bug?

Comment: No. Could be a hint -- but such a bug ..?

Comment: Now I have tested on another w10-FF61.01 like mine and the upload did work without an Add-file delay. But the upload didn't function entirely though, have to fix some promise rejections, thanks for the hint! -- Still I hope to find somebody who did experience this Dropbox Add-queue freeze-delay ...